Gifting $10k to my 17 year old nephew
I am very close with my nephew, and I've been saving a little bit here and there throughout his life to give him before college. I now have about $10,000 in my investment account earmarked for him. I'm trying to think through all the options (and their pros/cons) in terms of how to gift this money to him. Relevant info:

he is 17 now, 18 next year.
he has a job, but makes ~$2000/yr from it.
he will be going to a 4-yr college, and will need both loans and financial aid.

The options I've found are:

Check/cash, directly to him.
Open a 529 in his name.
Open a UTMA in his name.
Help seed a Roth IRA in his name.

(4) was originally my choice, but his low income (and not filing a tax return) makes me think it wont be feasible. (3) Seems like the next nicest option, but afaict it will count against his financial aid.
Are there other options available? What other information should I use to make this decision?
My objective is to jump-start his long-term savings, but I also wouldn't be opposed to helping him pay for college (hence the 529).

Will you be heartbroken if he spends it on something besides education? Consider giving 1/4, then 1/4 after each successful year.

"Are there other options available?" - I think the question might be a bit under-constrained. Obviously yes, there are other options available, for example gift him reasonably liquid non-cash assets like gold, bitcoin, shares, bonds, that could serve as savings. But I can't imagine you don't know that, so what's the missing constraint that meant you didn't even bother listing it? :-) I ask because littleadv suggests paying the tuition directly. That's a less obvious non-cash option, and you might get other such suggestions if readers have a better idea what you haven't already discarded.

It's too late now, but it probably would have been better if you had been saving this money in a 529 plan all along, rather than waiting until you need to start paying for college. You would have been avoiding taxes while the money accumulated.

And, maybe this verges on an answer, but: if your best outcome is to jump-start his long-term savings it might be better to wait until graduation. He's about to borrow and spend huge amounts of money (larger than the $10k), and realistically he might not prioritise savings over taking less debt, without a strong steer. So, giving him something that looks like savings might be more effective than giving him something that looks like cash. If it must look like cash then holding off until he's done taking the loans might be more effective.

@SteveJessop: I agree this is a bit under-constrained, but only because I don't know how I would explicitly constrain it further. Informally, I want to give himoney he feels like is his, and he is entitled to spend it any way he wants. But  the cost of college will likely dominate his financial concerns for the next 4 years, so helping with that is likely where the money goes anyway. I really like your framing of cash vs. savings. I almost want to sit down with him and ask him what he'd prefer: jump-start his retirement or pay off some college costs now.

@SteveD: sounds sensible. The tension is "saving regularly is a good habit" vs "you're paying higher interest on the debt than you earn on the asset, and spending less is a good habit too". Yet another way to frame it is the "emergency fund" - $10k is a very comfortable sum to have available for unexpected expenses, but if he already has such a sum (from another uncle?) then it might be better to use half of the combined $20k to avoid debt. You could end up quite deep into financial planning, but someone has to teach young adults this stuff.

... and some people benefit from their savings being "locked away". I don't really buy the whole "people aged under 25 have terrible impulse-control because their brains aren't fully formed", because it's a matter of tendencies not absolutes. But there's something in it, and at any age some people just economise better if they don't have cash in hand. Certainly I think it's worth talking to him to let him know that, while the money is 100% his, you have certain intentions in giving it to him. Since you're close he'll care what those intentions are.

Basically I assume what you don't want is for him to think he's supposed to spend it all on a $10k 18th birthday gift for himself, and buy something fun but ephemeral like a vacation? Not that travel is bad, but that it's not what you're aiming for on this occasion.

@SteveJessop: yes you've nailed it, I want him to use it wisely, but I don't want to do it for him. I will definitely be talking to him directly, I like that idea.

One perspective: $10.000 will make a big difference in his life now and during college. But the older he gets (and if he gets a good job) the less it will be. For retirement-plans 10k over 20-30 years will not make a big difference, so I would help him kickstart his life and career now.

Firmly agree with @SteveJessop that gifts like this are for people who have achieved college, and IMO started a professional job.  Kids in college don't need money, they have all the energy in the world


(4) was originally my choice, but his low income (and not filing a tax return) makes me think it wont be feasible.

It is. If he earns $2K/yr you can help him seed the Roth IRA with $2K each year.

(3) Seems like the next nicest option, but afaict it will count against his financial aid.

AFAIK all the three remaining options will show up on FAFSA and will be counted into the assets available to him.
You can also pay his tuition for him, so that it doesn't get added to his assets. That would help him take less loans and use his money elsewhere. It doesn't have to be through a 529 or giving money directly to him, you can just pay the money directly to the school.

Thank you for the answer! Afaict since I'm not his guardian, a 529 I open won't count against his financial aid. For the Roth IRA, does he need a tax return, or just earned income?

Why does he need to file a tax return? Is he self employed? If he's a W2 employee then the IRS already knows how much he earned.

Oh sorry, I was reading some things online about opening a custodial Roth IRA, and it was unclear (to me) if a tax return was required or not.
